# How to read and write parquet files using python version 2.7 or less

Tags: python, automation, parquet

I wanted to read -> update -> write parquet files using python 2.7 or less version. facing issue related to packages. please let me know the correct way to do the same.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using fastparquet and parquet  but no luck. its not able to fulfill requirement of packages in 2.7.

Comment: Your information about the problem is too low. You have to tell us 1. how did you install fastparquet? 2.what is the python code you wrote. The problem may be related to these questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyarrow` to read Parquet files with Python 2.7, see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html Note that there are no Python 2.7 wheels available for Windows. You either need to use `conda` there or switch to Linux / OSX.

Read Parquet files:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table("file.parquet")
# Optionally convert to Pandas DataFrame
df = table.to_pandas()
```

Write Parquet files:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# If your input data is a Pandas DataFrame, we need to convert it to an Arrow table first.
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, "filename.parquet")
```

Comment: Thanks it is working till reading parquet file,but i want to update few of the records as well and then write those updated records in different file.